# Sequelize: can attribute have value from relation attribute data?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i don't know if this is possible, there are 2 models which are associated through relation, and models are defined this way:

```
sequelize.define('account_has_plan', {
        account_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            references: {
                model: 'account',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        plan_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            references: {
                model: 'plan',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        type_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            references: {
                model: 'type',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        create_at: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
            defaultValue: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
        },
        update_at: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
            defaultValue: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'account_has_plan',
        underscored: true,
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false
    });

sequelize.define('type', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        element: {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM('Meal','Workout','Status'),
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'type',
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false
    });
```

the code on which calls the models and execute the query to DB is this:

```
var model = $.loadModel("account_has_plan");
var type  = $.loadModel("type");


model.belongsTo(type);

var query = {
    where: {
        account_id: $.params.accountId
    },
    limit: $.query.limit || 12,
    offset: $.query.offset || 0,
    attributes:["account_id"],
    include: [{
        model: type
    }]
};

model.findAll(query)
    .then(function(data){
        $.data = data;
        $.json();
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        errorHandler.throwStatus(500, $);
    });
```

this way the data from the server responds like this:

```
{
    "account_id": 1,
    "type": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Arms",
      "element": "Workout"
    }
  }
```

there is actually no problem with this data, but i am forced to follow a pattern from docs i was provided with, which the difference there is that `type` is actually a string value rather than object value as presented in the example, so in the end the data structure i try to get has to be like this:

```
{
    "account_id": 1,
    "type": "Arms"
}
```

i have actually how idea on how to achieve this, i know i have little practice with sequelize, maybe this has to be defined through a model method or using `through` in the reference (which i have tried but returns error)
but the point is.. i need to know if it can be possible before i have to report a change on the REST documentation which is big

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since what you'll be getting through a sequelize query are instances, you need to convert it to "plain" object. You could do that by using a module called [sequelize-values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-values).

Then you should be able to manually map the value to the one you're looking for.

```
model.findAll(query)
.then(function(data){
    return data.map(function(d){
        var rawValue = d.getValues();
        rawValue.type = rawValue.type.name;
        return rawValue;
    });
})
.then(function(data){
    $.data = data;
    $.json();
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
    errorHandler.throwStatus(500, $);
});
```

Comment: This is useful, but i want to know if there is a way to achieve this without the need of downloading a module or making this logic outside the model